# How do you multiply two unequal length vectors by a factor?

Tags: r

I have two data frames of differing lengths. There is a unique factor that links the two data frames together. I want to multiply the values in the larger data frame by the matching factor in the smaller data frame. Here is code to demonstrate:

```
d1 <- data.frame(u = factor(x = LETTERS[1:5]), n1 = 1:5)
d2 <- data.frame(u = factor(x = rep(x = LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)), n2 = 1:10)
```

I want `d2[1:2, 2]` both multiplied by `d1[1, 2]` because the factor "A" matches and so forth for the rest of the matching factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this problem you can also use `match`, which should be somewhat more efficient than the [`merge`/`transform` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26583270/489704) (particularly if you don't need the data.frame that the latter creates):

```
d2$n2 * d1[match(d2$u, d1$u), 'n1']

# [1]  1  2  6  8 15 18 28 32 45 50
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge` to join the two data frames, then `transform` to add a column to it.

```
> transform(merge(d1, d2), n.total = n1*n2)

   u n1 n2 n.total
1  A  1  1       1
2  A  1  2       2
3  B  2  3       6
4  B  2  4       8
5  C  3  5      15
6  C  3  6      18
7  D  4  7      28
8  D  4  8      32
9  E  5  9      45
10 E  5 10      50
```

If you don't need the data frame created by `transform` you can use `with` instead.

```
> with(merge(d1, d2), n1*n2)

 [1]  1  2  6  8 15 18 28 32 45 50
```

If you have a lot of data and the above solutions are too slow or inefficient I suggest you go for @jbaums solution, but otherwise I find that the increased readability of `merge` is preferable.

```
> require(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(transform(merge(d1, d2), n.total = n1*n2),
+                with(merge(d1, d2), n1*n2),
+                d2$n2 * d1[match(d2$u, d1$u), 'n1'])

Unit: microseconds
                                        expr     min       lq       mean
 transform(merge(d1, d2), n.total = n1 * n2) 826.897 904.2275 1126.41204
                with(merge(d1, d2), n1 * n2) 658.295 722.6715  907.34581
         d2$n2 * d1[match(d2$u, d1$u), "n1"]  49.372  59.5830   78.42575
   median        uq      max neval cld
 940.3890 1087.0350 2695.521   100   c
 764.2965  934.5555 2463.300   100  b 
  66.2475   86.1505  260.820   100 a
```

Answer (score 2):

If we into speed comparisons, you might just as well try `data.table` package (although for such a small data set, jbaums approach probably be more efficient)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(d1), u); setDT(d2)
d1[d2][, n.total := n1*n2][]
#     u n1 n2 n.total
#  1: A  1  1       1
#  2: A  1  2       2
#  3: B  2  3       6
#  4: B  2  4       8
#  5: C  3  5      15
#  6: C  3  6      18
#  7: D  4  7      28
#  8: D  4  8      32
#  9: E  5  9      45
# 10: E  5 10      50
```

---

Or as (suggested by @Arun)

```
d2[d1, n2 := n2*n1] # Update (by reference) `n2`
```

OR

```
d2[d1, new := n2*n1] # Add new column
```

Note: Although these would be faster, you won't see column `n1` in the final result